# Rendering colorpicker

Tags: c, colors, color-picker

Yes, of course i could render color picker by my own. But it won't be as much productive and handy then that one:
[image]

It is the GNU color-picker which most likely means GTK+ which means C.

Assume i have a function void `setpen(R, G, B, transp, size);`
And void `putpixel(X, Y);`
Those two functions have to be enough.

What i don't understand is how is the gamma field is drawn.
It looks really confusing. If i have the gamma field i can easily then change
the value and render the color rainbow. How am i supposed to draw the gamma field using loops. It looks confusing.. black/white and red gammas as default.

The pixel aligment looks confusing..
The solution of this question might contain using math functions.
I noticed that y controls saturation - r,g,b values and y the lightness of r,g,bs

I wish i could draw it with something like that

```
for(lightness = 0; lightness < 148; lightness++)
{
    for(satur = 0; satur < 159; satur++)
    {
        setpen(r, g, b, 0, 1);
        putpixel(lightness, satur);
```

Comment: Define `gamma field`...

Comment: The field in left of the rainbow values.

Comment: It looks to me like a simple mapping of SATURATION x LIGHTNESS  cartesian product.

Comment: It is. y dedicates saturation and x lightness

Comment: so what confuses you now? hsl to rgb conversion?

Comment: The rendering? How am i supposed to render the field using the putpixel function. I can render simple gradients but i dont understand how to render that one.

Answer (score 0):

The field is a grid, say `10x10`

Start at `[0, 0]`, with value `(0, 0)` and (bi)linearly interpolate for each dimension (x and y, so that's two loops) up to `[10, 10]`, and convert the HSL for each coordinate you're currently on to RGB, and apply that to set the brush with `setpen`.

I believe this should do the job.

Comment: Don't know what is HSL and how to convert to it.
But it might stand for HueSaturationLightness.

Comment: Search for `HSL to RGB` here on SO, you'll find many implementations.

Comment: i am not that good in math. I doubt i can handle this :(
Considering the wiki page for HSL

Comment: If this is a school assignment, pair up with someone that can teach and work with you. I'm sure there's such a student for you :) 
But, most importantly: YES, you can handle this, be patient and believe in yourself.

Comment: Hehe. It is for my own project. And i am from another Country. Not a native and there are noone interested in this here.

Answer (score 0):

This is a projection of cylindrical coordinates of Lightness.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#Lightness

If you have a means to calculate a color from (H, S, L) values, then simply use this function. Vary H as (x, y) with color A and color B, also vary L as (x, y) from 0 to max lightness.

Comment: I can't find there a color scheme that looks like that one.
All of the HSVs contain two colors.